# Detect if speakers are plugged in?

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, audio

Is there any way to detect if computer has speakers plugged in? It would be nice if that would be possible with JavaScript, but if not, then my best bet would be Java.

But, yeah, I haven't worked with Java at all, any useful resources on this?

Thanks in advance!

## EDIT:

So the answer for this is "impossible" and I shouldn't even bother looking for a solution?

Comment: Is there anyway to detect this with the computer in general, full stop?  I do not recall it being a standard sound card feature.  Even if plugged in, are they on, is the volume up, etc.

Comment: Whi is there a `jQuery` tag on it?

Comment: @Gentleman: because JavaScript == jQuery, and in case there was a JavaScript solution which could be done easier/simplier with jQuery, people would know that they can use that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The computer itself is not, in general, aware of this.
Some audio drivers are, but they don't expose the information.

Comment: Depends on the hardware i gues http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/1647/how-does-an-audio-jack-detect-when-a-speaker-is-plugged-in

Comment: Ah, actually I wasn't aware of this, because all the PCs I've been using lately have that Realtek soundcards (integrated) with appropriate drivers installed, and always displays a message when jack is plugged/unplugged.

Answer (score 6):

Every piece of software I've seen that needs to determine such a thing provides a way for the user to play a "test sound" and give the application some appropriate feedback. That seems to be the most practical solution.

Comment: nice to see you around.  I was surprised when I came here and did not see you as a top answerer.

Comment: Well... I somehow thought that it was possible and could be easily read. Guess not. And I wanted to display an error message if the user had no sound output devices plugged in.